# JsonIgnore property if called from entity relation

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I'm trying to conditionally `@JsonIgnore` some fields from an entity if they're serialized from an other entity's collection (many to one).

I've tried to add `@JsonIgnoreProperties` to the collection but as I understand that annotation is not for this purpose.

```
class A {
    //some fields

    @ManyToOne private B b; //if only A is requested, this should NOT be ignored    
}

class B {
    //some fields

    @OneToMany
    @IgnorePrivateBInAToAvoidStackOverflow
    private Set<A> collectionOfAs;
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this behavior?

Comment: is it possible to modify the configuration of jackson mapper for each case?

Comment: @SharonBenAsher I'm afraid that there won't be any annotation supporting my case, so yes, it may be modifiable.

Comment: see if this helps http://springquay.blogspot.com/2016/01/new-approach-to-solve-json-recursive.html

Comment: @buræquete yes I did but it omitted one side or the another, depending on which was chosen as back and managed (class A is also accessed individually).

Comment: It is due to [this](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1878) I guess, it was working as intended when I was using it... :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid circular reference Infinite recursion ( stackoverflow error ) you have to annotate calss with [@JsonIdentityInfo](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIdentityInfo.html)

So you class looks like :

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(
       generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
       property = "id")
class A {
    //some fields
    //Integer id;


    @OneToMany private B b; //if only A is requested, this should NOT be ignored    
}
```

Same thing for class B to bidirectional  use :

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(
       generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
       property = "id")
class B {
    //some fields

    @ManyToOne
    @IgnorePrivateBInAToAvoidStackOverflow
    private Set<A> collectionOfAs;
}
```

be aware that the `property` refers to your unique field name ( set to `id`  in this example )

for more reading see this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-advanced-annotations)

Answer (score 3):

Your usage of `@ManyToOne` & `@OneToMany` is incorrect, you must use `@OneToMany` within the `One` entity on the `Many` entity collection property, and vice-versa for `@ManyToOne`

```
class A {

    @ManyToOne 
    @JsonBackReference
    private B b;
}

class B {

    @OneToMany
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<A> collectionOfAs;
}
```

and as far as I can understand, you'd like to ignore the owner `B` for doing a back reference from class `A`, and create a stackoverflow exception, to achieve that use the annotation I've added in my above example `@JsonBackReference` & `@JsonManagedReference` which will stop the infinite loop on its tracks.

Answer (score 0):

If Class B has a collection of Class A then the Set of A in the Class B should be annotated `@OneToMany`, and the field in class A should be annotated `@ManyToOne`, then you can put your `@JsonIgnore` on the set like so:

```
class A {
    //some fields

    @ManyToOne private B b; //if only A is requested, this should NOT be ignored    
}

class B {
    //some fields


    @OneToMany
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<A> collectionOfAs;
}
```

My guess is that you were receiving StackOverflow error because when you were fetching some object of Class B, it brought the Set of objects of Class As with it, which themselves brought the same object of Class B which was originally fetched, and this would go infinitely, unless you provided @JsonIgnore on the Set field. This way, when you call an object of Class A, their field object of Class B will also be fetched, but when you call an object of Class B, their collection of Class As will be ignored.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution that only ignores the B field of A if it's accessed through the collection, not omitting the whole collection.

Answer (score 0):

That shoud work with `@JsonIgnoreProperties`

```
class A {
    //some fields

    @ManyToOne private B b; //if only A is requested, this should NOT be ignored    
}

class B {
    //some fields


    @OneToMany
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({'b', 'otherField'})
    private Set<A> collectionOfAs;
}
```